# Equivalent of tf.keras.layers.Input in pytorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torch

What is the equivalent of

```
ops = tf.keras.layers.Input(
    shape=[hilbert_size, hilbert_size, num_points * 2], name="operators"
)
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(num_points), name="inputs")
```

from tensorflow in pytorch?

I'm writing a cGAN in torch from a code that I wrote in tensorflow. It's kind of a translation. What I did in torch is:

```
    ops = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(1, hilbert_size, hilbert_size, num_points * 2))
    inputs = torch.empty((1, 1296), requires_grad=True)
```

The outputs in tensorflow are:

```
In [59]: ops
Out[59]: <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 16, 16, 2592) dtype=float64 (created by layer 'operators')>

In [60]: inputs
Out[60]: <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 1296) dtype=float64 (created by layer 'inputs')>
```

But the code in torch gives:

```
In [6]: ops
Out[6]: 
Parameter containing:
tensor([[[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     ...,

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]], requires_grad=True)

In [7]: inputs
Out[7]: 
tensor([[-1.8727e+27,  4.5817e-41,  1.3275e-17,  ...,  4.5817e-41,
     -7.5189e+25,  4.5817e-41]], requires_grad=True)
```

Is it right? Is this the correct way of instantiate inputs for a neural network in torch?
It makes sense to me that the inputs is a vector of shape `torch.Size([1, 1296])` but the corresponding code in tensorflow gives `TensorShape([None, 1296])` and the `Out[60]` line in the code above gives as output an object that is a layer and not a tensor like the output from torch. I'm not sure if I'm going the right tway

Comment: The Input Layer in tensorflow most often is a wrapper for the tensor to pass to the network or the next layer. But pytorch requires the data to be a tensor so it is fine. I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observations are correct regarding the differences between TensorFlow and PyTorch, more specifically:

1. **TensorFlow's `Input` vs. PyTorch's `tensor`**:

   - In TensorFlow, `tf.keras.layers.Input` defines the shape of the input placeholder but does not hold any data itself. It's more like defining the shape and type of the input that a model will expect. It returns a `KerasTensor` object, which is a symbolic representation, and you can think of it as a placeholder for the actual data.
   - In PyTorch, tensors are multi-dimensional arrays that can hold actual data. Therefore, when you define a tensor like `torch.empty((1, 1296), requires_grad=True)`, you're creating an actual tensor with uninitialized data of shape `[1, 1296]`.
2. **Differences in Batch Dimension**:

   - TensorFlow's `Input` uses `None` for the batch dimension to indicate that the batch size is dynamic and can change.
   - In PyTorch, if you define a tensor of shape `[1, 1296]`, it means the batch size is fixed to 1. In most cases, during the actual training or inference, you'll pass data with variable batch sizes.
3. **Instantiating Inputs in PyTorch**:

   - The way you've instantiated `inputs` using `torch.empty` is one way to do it, but it creates an uninitialized tensor. If you want it to be initialized with zeros (similar to TensorFlow's default), you can use `torch.zeros` instead.
   - The `nn.Parameter` is generally used for tensors that should be optimized, like weights and biases in a model. If `ops` should be optimized during training (like model weights), then using `nn.Parameter` is correct.

Given your context, here's a closer match to the TensorFlow code:

```py
ops = torch.zeros(1, hilbert_size, hilbert_size, num_points * 2)
# If ops should be optimized during training:
ops = nn.Parameter(ops)

inputs = torch.zeros(1, 1296, requires_grad=True)
```

Keep in mind:

- In real training or inference scenarios, you'll probably use the model's `forward` method to pass inputs, which means you'll create and pass tensors of the appropriate shape and type as needed.
- If `ops` is supposed to be a parameter of the model (something you want the optimizer to update), then using `nn.Parameter` is correct. If not, you should treat it like any other tensor input.
- You should ensure that tensors are initialized appropriately before use. Using uninitialized tensors like with `torch.empty` can lead to unpredictable results if the data isn't subsequently overwritten with valid values.